# date gets converted to 1969 while using the php date function

Tags: php, php4

Why do I get 1969 when I convert the following date to Y-m-d format.

```
$date1="01/02/2012";
echo date('Y-m-d',$date1);
```

NOTE: This is php4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to convert the date string to a timestamp:

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date1));
```